# How to mimic Amazon's Word Wise anotation feature

Tags: css, annotations, definition, epub, kindle

When enabled, eInk Kindles and some Kindle apps display definitions above less frequently used words. For example:

[image: Kinde Word Wise screenshot]

I tried to emulate this feature with <ruby> tags, but it didn't work when the definition was longer than the defined word. Also, if you look closer at the screen capture, you'll notice that there's also a vertical bracket(?) above each word that matches its length.

What would be the best approach to mimic this layout using only HTML5 and CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's a basic version of how I would do this, although I can see some trouble in specific scenarios where the explanations of side-by-side words overlap.

First I wrapped each word inside a `span` element and added a `data-tooltip` attribute with the word explanation. I styled using pseudo elements so that the explanations are absolutely positioned at the top of each word and added a border-top with another pseudo element on the word-to-be-explained to fake the arrow tip.

CSS:

```
body {
  font-size:22px;
}
[data-tooltip] {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:20px;
  border-top:1px solid red;
}
[data-tooltip]:before {
  content:attr(data-tooltip);
  font-size:12px;
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  /* left:0; */
  margin-top:-20px;
}
[data-tooltip]:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:6px;
  height:6px;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-right:1px solid red;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-3px;
  top:-4px;
  background:#fff;
}
[data-tooltip].left:before {
  left: 0 !important;
}
[data-tooltip].right:before {
  right: 0 !important;  
}
[data-tooltip].center:before {
  left: 50% !important;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Additionally, using `Javascript`, I took the length of each `paragraph` (assumed all have same `width`) and create an if statement for the 3 following scenarios:
- the word-to-be-explained is before the first 1/3 of the paragraph length
- the word-to-be-explained is after the 2/3 of the paragraph length
- the word-to-be-explained is between the two above statements
... and adjusted the explanation accordingly by applying classes `left`, `right` or `center` accordingly.

Javascript

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    pw = $('p').first().width();
  $('[data-tooltip]').each(function() {
    pos = $(this).offset().left;
    if (pos < pw/3) {
    console.log('run');
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('left');
    } else if (pos > pw*2/3) {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('right');
    } else if ((pos > pw/3) && (pos < pw*2/3)) {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('center');
    }
  })
})
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fgnp07ty/1/

In case where explanations of two words that are side-by-side are too long and overlap, you would have to either limit explanation width to the word length and add ellipsis at the end (...) - I would go with this solution, or calculate explanation lengths and adjust accordingly - this is too much tbh.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can work for you:

```css
p{
line-height:2em;
}
span{
position:relative;
}
span:after{
content: "";
    width: 0.3rem;
    height: 0.3rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: solid 1px coral;
    border-left: solid 1px coral;
    background: white;
    top: -0.1rem;
    left: 10%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
span:before{
content:"the definition of penatibus";
font-size:.7em;
line-height:1rem;
color:coral;
position:absolute;
top:-1rem;
white-space:nowrap;
border-bottom:solid 1px coral;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque <span>penatibus</span> et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It works, but I prefer scooterlord's solution.